# Why Console.ReadLine() freezes for a few seconds on start?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When I run this simple program

```
var s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

5 of 6 times The Console opens and it freezes for a 5-6 seconds and then it shows the string I entered. Is this some sort of bug of Visual Studio 2017 Community and do you have any ideas how can I fix this ?

Comment: @nKolachakoV can you provide all of your code?

Comment: It's standart. https://pastebin.com/SqGnPwnM

Comment: Also with every project that starts with some sort of input  and have nothing before it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the cause might be that the app is waiting for the Debugger to attach before you are able to interact with it. Even then it seems like a rather long time, so I would suggest trying to repair Visual Studio

Comment: Ok I will try it now. If I set a breakpoint at the end of the program and run it in debug mode, then everything works fine and doesn't freeze, soo maybe this can be the case.

Comment: I would definitely try to open the project folder, navigate to bin/Debug and just run the app from the file explorer. If it doesn't freeze, then Visual Studio must be the cause